# Formula for this game

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are two players A and B. Given K,L a player A can pick 1, or K
>   or L coins($1<K<L$)  from the M coins then player B can pick 1 or K or L
>   coins from the remaining coins, and      the
>
> process will repeat. The player which picks last coin will win the game. Now I need to tell which player will win if both
>   of them plays optimally.

Example:
K = 2 L = 3 and M = 3 --> player A will win.

K= 2 L = 3 and M = 12 --> player B will win.

I solved this problem using dynamic programming but there is formula for this problem. Can anybody help me to derive the formula.

Comment: Does winning mean taking the last coin or avoiding taking the last coin?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Ohh I am really sorry I forgot to mention that please see the edited question.